# Using Bootstrap CSS I want to show proper mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my website to be mobile responsive and want the mobile view to have this kind of changes. I would like to mention adding `cd-xs-12` does not make any changes or even `cd-sm-12` does not get me what I want.

[image]

here's my existing code

```css
.mobile-select {height:50px;padding-top:15px;padding-left:60px;padding-right:20px}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row breadcrumb bg-white border-bottom paddl30">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Devices</a></li>
      <li> &gt; </li>
      <li>Screen Analytics</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row mobile-select border-bottom">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ul class="device-menu bg-white">
      <li class="selected">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mobileAppScreens">Mobile</a>
        <span class="sub-menu-menu"> 
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="iosMobileAppScreens" class="checked"> <i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true" ></i> ios</a>

         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="androidMobileAppScreens"><i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Android</a>
        </span>
        <span class="grey-pipe">|</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tabletAppScreens">Tablet</a>
        <span class="sub-menu-menu hide"> 
         <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
         <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="iostabletAppScreens"><i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true"></i> ios</a>

        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click=""  id="androidtabletAppScreens"> <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Android</a>
        </span>
      </li>
      <li class="hidden">
        <input type="text" id="selMenu" value="iosMobileAppScreens">
        <input type="text" id="sDate">
        <input type="text" id="eDate">
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div id="dateRangescreenAnalytics" class="pull-right">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar txt-green fa fa-calendar"></i>
      <span></span><b class="caret"></b>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Solution -- add `<br class="visible-xs">` wherever needed.

Comment: Please share full code. It doesnt have your css.

Comment: @TanviChaturvedi updated

Answer (score 0):

Just add clearfixes, man. Something like this:

```
<div class=clearfix></div>
```

And in styles it should be like this:

```
.clearfix {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: that doesn't help much -- it makes the calender look ok but still the upper part is as the same.

Comment: have you tried to add same div after your ios link?

Comment: yes, I did. It does'nt make any changes apart from the iOs icon being on the next line plus - that way it changes the desktop view to this -- which is not desired.

Comment: try to add margin via @media

Answer (score 0):

Inside your head tag, put these lines.

`<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>`

And also re-check your div tags and make sure you did a correct element placements.

Comment: tryed this - no impacts

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps! Added col-xs-12 to correctly render heights of the elements. "*" will be your identifier in the code to check modifications.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

    <style >

    .mobile-select {height:50px;padding-top:15px;padding-left:60px;padding-right:20px}
    </style>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <div class="row breadcrumb bg-white border-bottom paddl30">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <ul **class="breadcrumb"**>
          <li><a href="">Devices</a></li>
          <li> &gt; </li>
          <li>Screen Analytics</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mobile-select border-bottom">
      <div class="col-md-6 **col-xs-12**">
        <ul class="device-menu bg-white **col-xs-12**">
          <li class="selected **col-xs-12**">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="mobileAppScreens">Mobile</a>
            <span class="sub-menu-menu"> 
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="iosMobileAppScreens" class="checked"> <i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true" ></i> ios</a>

                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="androidMobileAppScreens"><i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Android</a>
                                    </span>
            <span class="grey-pipe">|</span>
          </li>
          <li **class="col-xs-12"**>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="tabletAppScreens">Tablet</a>
            <span class="sub-menu-menu hide"> 
                                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="" id="iostabletAppScreens"><i class="fa fa-apple" aria-hidden="true"></i> ios</a>

                                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click=""  id="androidtabletAppScreens"> <i class="fa fa-android" aria-hidden="true"></i> Android</a>
                                    </span>
          </li>
          <li class="hidden">
            <input type="text" id="selMenu" value="iosMobileAppScreens">
            <input type="text" id="sDate">
            <input type="text" id="eDate">
          </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 **col-xs-12**">
        <div id="dateRangescreenAnalytics" class="pull-right">
          <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar txt-green fa fa-calendar"></i>
          <span></span><b class="caret"></b>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<!-- end snippet -->




</html>
```

Comment: that also does'nt solve it, rather I have found another hack, I am adding <br class="visible-xs">  (where needed) and it works magic. Thanks for help though.